# Flex i18n Issues (selecting Locale in onCreationComplete)

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5

Alright.  I've been going around the net trying to find a way to do internatinoalization without a headache; and I finally found on means.  Including the locale in your build params, and doing that `-locale locale/{locale}` thing to make them be properties files for the resource manager (ie: `locale/en_GB/lang.properties` in src folder.)

Problem:  I can't seem to set the user's locale on startup.  I get some error about "LocaleID index out of range" (which is odd, since LocaleID is String based..?)

**This part works fine:**

```
<fx:Script> 
    <![CDATA[
        // Shorthand resource management.
        private function getLang(key:String):String
        { return resourceManager.getString(key, 'lang'); }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

**This part does not work:**

```
protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    var locale:LocaleID = new LocaleID("en_GB");
    trace(locale.getLanguage()); // en
    trace(locale.getRegion()); // GB
    trace(locale.name); // en-GB

    if (!empty(saveData.data.lang)) // empty checks if str == null or trim(str).length == 0
        locale = new LocaleID(saveData.data.lang);

    this.setStyle("locale", locale);
}
```

The actual error is not thrown when I set the locale, but when objects in the UI try to get their values.  The full error message is below:

```
RangeError: Property locale value [object LocaleID] is out of range
    at flashx.textLayout.property::Property$/defaultErrorHandler()[C:\Vellum\branches\v2\2.0\dev\output\openSource\textLayout\src\flashx\textLayout\property\Property.as:31]
    at flashx.textLayout.property::Property/setHelper()[C:\Vellum\branches\v2\2.0\dev\output\openSource\textLayout\src\flashx\textLayout\property\Property.as:230]
    at flashx.textLayout.formats::TextLayoutFormat/setStyleByProperty()[C:\Vellum\branches\v2\2.0\dev\output\openSource\textLayout\src\flashx\textLayout\formats\TextLayoutFormat.as:628]
    at flashx.textLayout.formats::TextLayoutFormat/set locale()[C:\Vellum\branches\v2\2.0\dev\output\openSource\textLayout\src\flashx\textLayout\formats\TextLayoutFormat.as:1271]
    at spark.core::CSSTextLayoutFormat()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\core\CSSTextLayoutFormat.as:75]
    at spark.components::RichEditableText/updateStylesIfChanged()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\RichEditableText.as:3619]
    at spark.components::RichEditableText/commitProperties()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\RichEditableText.as:2491]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/validateProperties()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8209]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateProperties()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:597]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:813]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiationCallback()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:1180]
```

**Fun Facts**:
1. My name is not Vellum (?)
2. My sdk isn't in `E:\dev\4.5.1` ... it's in `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5.1\sdks\4.5.1`.  Good job error messages!  Using the original build paths and all...

Comment: The issue w/ build paths showing up in the stack trace relates to how the framework SWCs are built.  I think it is impossible to remove those dev paths when you create a "FAT SWC" which includes all the ASDocs and metadata used to create the code hinting.  I'm a bit blurry on details; but that is my understanding.

Comment: I managed to get around this question in a very nasty way, so I suppose I'll write the answer.  I just hate Flex more and more every day as I see how poorly Adobe's done it.

Comment: As an FYI, these runtime errors are generated from the textLayout framework; not from Flex Framework code.  I'm not saying that Flex is without issue; but your current error is not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

The actual "fix" for this issue was disgusting, but it worked:

```
protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    var locale:String = LocaleID.DEFAULT.name.replace("-", "_"); // en_GB

    if (!empty(saveData.data.lang)) // empty checks if str == null or trim(str).length == 0
        locale = saveData.data.lang;

    resourceManager.localeChain = [locale, "en_GB"];
}
```

Why?  Because it seems that the Flex docs (such wonderful things) are yet again, outdated.  The use of `this.setStyle("locale", locale)` is actually erroneous in Flex4.5.  Instead you update the resourceManager's languageChain to include your preferred locale as the first preference.

Ad per the ugly naming line, it's the only way to get "en_GB" out of a `LocaleID`.  Either that or string concatenation, which is also pretty ugly.  Too bad the `resourceManager` doesn't take dashes as underscores like it should.

Answer (score 0):

The [locale style](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/Container.html#style%3alocale) should have a string value; but you are setting it with a LocaleID Object.  I'm pretty sure you want to do this:

```
this.setStyle("locale", "en_GB");
```

Here is some more information on the [LocaleID object](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS19f279b149e7481c-11cc159f12ea10f6efe-7ffa.html).

Comment: Yes and no, unfortunately; setting it like that also gives the same odd range error.  I had tried that solution before posting on here, when I ran across the LocaleID thing; people telling me to use it and LocaleID.DEFAULT ... :(